# Galois Bicentennial?

Tags: nt.number-theory, gr.group-theory

The 200-th anniversary of the birth of Galois will be on October 25th, 2011. For Abel's bicentennial birth year in 2002, Norway had a big conference and initiated the Abel prize. A cursory web search doesn't reveal any major (or minor) conference to mark the bicentennial for Galois. Is there something being planned that hasn't been broadly announced yet?

[Edit: Before posting this question, I looked at the number theory conference page http://www.numbertheory.org/ntw/N3.html and found nothing there related to my question.]

I realize that is not a math research question, but I don't think it should be closed since it should interest many users of this site, it should have a definite answer, and it is not "argumentative", "too localized" (at what prime?) or "not a real question".

[Edit: Now that Emerton has answered the question well and nobody else has followed up after several days with other replies, I suspect he has given the best possible answer and I have designated it as such.]

Comment: By the way, the annoucement of the Abel Prize 2011 winner is tomorrow.

Comment: I hope they don't start a Galois Prize...

Comment: Denis, I didn't even realize that. 

Comment: Tomorrow is also Emmy Noether's birthday. :)

Comment: See this stamp showing Galois: http://mathsetcalculs.perso.neuf.fr/Timbres/tgalois.htm

Comment: There are plenty of mathematicians either born or the other on March 23 here: http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/Day_files/Day323.html

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the number theory tag. 

Comment: Todd, I think some people only search for questions that are tagged as being in a certain area (their own area(s) of interest). So I used two tags for areas where I thought people might know about events related to the subject of the question: those working in number theory or group theory.

Comment: John Milnor:

http://www.thehindu.com/sci-tech/science/article1565424.ece

Comment: @Todd, you know, Galois wrote a paper about continued fractions. 

Comment: Gerry, I had in mind that Galois theory is fundamental to number theory.

Comment: @KConrad, I knew what you had in mind, I just thought I'd give some screentime to a little-known fact. 

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is a conference at the IHP in Paris on October 24-28 of this year in honour of this anniversary.   [Here](http://www.galois.ihp.fr) is the web-site, which doesn't have much information on it yet.

UPDATE: There is now quite a bit of information posted.

Answer (score 6):

The site mentioned by Emerton now lists a conference on [Équations différentielles et théorie de Galois](http://www.ihes.fr/jsp/site/Portal.jsp?document_id=2755&portlet_id=14), 17--21 October 2011, at the IHES.

**Update** (2012/01/11)  Videos of the lectures at the IHP conference are now available online at the [vidéothèque](http://www1.cpm.upmc.fr/videotheque/differe.php?collec=S_C_galois&video=13) of Université Pierre et Marie Curie.

Answer (score 3):

There is also some events (exhibitions, large audience talks) in Bourg la Reine, the town where Galois grew up (near Paris).

[Parlons d'Évariste Galois](http://www.bourg-la-reine.fr/Acces-directs/Actualites/Parlons-d-Evariste-Galois)