# More on "Transalgebraic Theories" (a 19th century yoga)?

Tags: nt.number-theory, ho.history-overview, galois-theory, big-picture, transcendental-number-theory

Among the talks at occasion of the [Galois Bicentennial](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/59155/galois-bicentennial), one is about ["Transalgebraic Theories"](http://www.ihes.fr/jsp/site/Portal.jsp?document_id=2755&portlet_id=14). Unfortunately I found only [this](http://garf.ub.es/milenio/img/Riemann.pdf) article describing that fascinating idea as " an extremely powerful 'philosophical' principle that some
mathematicians of the XIXth century seem to be well aware of. In general terms we
would say that analytically unsound manipulations provide correct answers when
they have an underlying transalgebraic background." Do you know more?

Edit: [This](http://www.rkmvu.ac.in/intro/academics/matsc_website/kingshook/allnew.pdf) text tells a few words more (e.g. "This philosophy can be linked to Kronecker’s ”Judgendtraum” and Hilbert’s twelfth problem, which seems to have remained largely misunderstood.") and refers to a manuscript "Transalgebraic Number Theory". Has someone a copy?

Comment: here is the abstract of that talk: "Galois' visions contained in his brouillons and manuscripts goes far beyond the classical algebraic and differential Galois Theory. The goal pursued by Galois was to classify not only algebraic numbers and functions, but also transcendental ones. This philosophy goes far beyond our actual knowledge. We will present some elements of transalgebraic function field theory, as well as transalgebraic applications to the theory of Riemann zeta function."

Comment: Thanks, Mattew! That makes one even more curious. I have not yet read the article linked to above and made my mind about it, but it looks as if there should be connections to periods, motives, F_un, etc. (?) 

Comment: Thomas, Could you check the links in your question? Some of them do not work, others apparently contain nothing related to your question.

Comment: I found this texts: http://garf.ub.es/milenio/img/Riemann.pdf , (my computer does not produce a readable thing out of this:) http://www.ihes.fr/document?id=2921&id_attribute=48 , (book on "log-Riemann surfaces"): maths.rkmvu.ac.in/~kingshook/allnew.pdf .

Comment: MathSciNet says, No publications results for 'Anywhere=(transalgebraic)'

Answer (score 8):

For the most part "transalgebraic theory" seems an umbrella term for anything that relates (classic, differential, motivic, categorical) Galois theory with periods, trascendence results, special values, regularization...

Here is a compilation of papers which might be of interest.

Yves André

- [Galois theory, motives and transcendental numbers](http://arxiv.org/abs/0805.2569)
- [Ambiguity theory, old and new](http://arxiv.org/abs/0805.2568)
- [Idées galoisiennes](http://arxiv.org/abs/1207.3381)

Michel Waldschmidt

- [Transcendence of Periods: The State of the Art](http://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~michel.waldschmidt/articles/pdf/TranscendencePeriods.pdf)
- Much more on trascendence on his [page](http://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~michel.waldschmidt/texts.html).

Alexandru Buium

- [Transcendental numbers as solutions to arithmetic differential equations](http://arxiv.org/abs/1408.6188)
- [Arithmetic differential equations on GLn, III: Galois groups](http://arxiv.org/abs/1308.0747)

Alain Connes

- [Renormalisation et ambiguïté galoisienne](http://www.alainconnes.org/docs/ramis.pdf)

Ricardo Pérez-Marco

- The "Transalgebraic Number Theory" manuscript still doesn't seem to be avaible online. The author is clearly active ([papers on arXiv](http://arxiv.org/find/math/1/au:+Perez_Marco_R/0/1/0/all/0/1)), so perhaps someone can ask him [directly](http://www.math.univ-paris13.fr/ann/indiv/?clef=PR/frnXzCp).
- The (only?) relevant online paper was alredy mentioned in the question, [Notes on the Riemann Hypothesis](http://garf.ub.es/milenio/img/Riemann.pdf).

Comment: There is also this on the Arxiv: http://arxiv.org/abs/1512.03776, Log-Riemann Surfaces by Kingshook Biswas and Ricardo Perez-Marco.